# drawing a perpendicular from a side of a triangle to one of its vertexes

Tags: intersections

Using tikz. I have an isosceles triangle ABC. BC forms the basis with the distances AC = AB. The two base angles are of the same size.

```
\begin{tikzpicture};
    \draw[thick] (0,0) coordinate (B) -- (65:8cm) coordinate (A) -- ++(65+50:-8cm) coordinate (C) -- cycle;

\tkzLabelPoint[above](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](C){$C$}

\draw[thick] (B) -- (20:6.2cm) coordinate (D);
\tkzLabelPoint[right](D){$D$};

 \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.8cm,color=red](B,D,C);
 \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.5, font=\scriptsize](B,D,C){$90^{\circ}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

How do I calculate the Perpendicular from AC to B? I want that the 90° label is true and I need the coordinates where the Perpendicular meets AC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\tkzDrawAltitude(A,C)(B) \tkzGetPoint{D}
```

instead of

```
\draw[thick] (B) -- (20:6.2cm) coordinate (D);
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture};
    \draw[thick] (0,0) coordinate (B) -- (65:8cm) coordinate (A) -- ++(65+50:-8cm) coordinate (C) -- cycle;

\tkzLabelPoint[above](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](C){$C$}

\tkzDrawAltitude(A,C)(B) \tkzGetPoint{D}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](D){$D$};

 \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.8cm,color=red](B,D,C);
 \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.5, font=\scriptsize](B,D,C){$90^{\circ}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```